# Azure Logic Apps vs Azure Automation what is the difference

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am a bit confused about using Azure Logic Apps vs Azure Automation to manage jobs for Azure Database. Which product should I use for Azure SQL Database?

Comment: azure logic apps is for managing a workflow. Azure automation is for creating runbooks to automate tasks like deployment, updates using powershell scripts, python scripts. If you are referring to SQL agent jobs those are available only in Azure SQL Managed Instance. SQL Agent Jobs are not available in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Since I am new I cannot give you points even though this is a valid answer.

Comment: That's fine. As long as you got an answer to your question it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reference what @Aravind said, Azure Logic Apps is for managing a workflow. It is more powerful than Azure Automation.
2. Azure automation is for creating runbooks to automate tasks like deployment, updates using powershell scripts, python scripts.
3. Due to SQL agent jobs those are available only in Azure SQL Managed Instance.
4. If you are using Azure SQL, there are multiple ways to run automated scripts on Azure SQL Database as below:

- Using Automation Account Runbooks.
- Using Elastic Database Jobs in Azure
- Using Azure Data factory.

If you are running just one or some simple scripts, I would suggest you to take a look into Automation Account Runbooks.